# How can display the data of particular month from database by select the particular month through drop down in php

Tags: php, html-select

I want to display the data of particular month when i select the month in drop down using php
**view.php**

```
<form action="#" method="POST">

<select name="month" id="month">
<option>
</option>
<option>
January
</option>
<option >
February
</option>
<option >
March
</option>


etc....
</select>
</form>


<form><input type="text" id="p"></form>
```

Comment: what do you meen under _display the data_?

Comment: Where do you want to display the data of particular month?

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with this:

```
<form action = '' method=POST>
<select name=month>
<option value=1>Jan</option>
<option value=2>Feb</option>
</select>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

the form handler

```
// a rudimentary filter for the incoming variable
if(int($_POST['month'] > 0 && int($_POST['month'] < 13){


// create your sql statement here

$sql = "select stuff from mytable where MONTH(yourdatefield) = " $_POST['month'] ;
echo $sql;
}else{
// someone is messing with your form values, send away ...
exit('cannot proceed');
}
```

caveats:

In this example `yourdatefield` should be a mysql DATE or TIMESTAMP field, it may differ with other RDBMSs

You will notice there is no YEAR filter, you may have to add that.

There is no check to see if $_POST['month'] is set, you will have to add that.